# How to write a type of string or a function callback in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, interface

```
export interface IBaseFormConfig {
    hints?: string | (Map<string, any>): string;
    validators?: any | (Map<string, any>): any;
}
```

This is not working. It is a decorator. So developers can decorate an attribute like:

```
@IBaseFormConfig({
    hints: 'This is the hint'
})

// or

@IBaseFormConfig({
    hints: () => {
        // Developers can resolve its hints dynamically with services.

        return 'This is the hint';
    }
})
```

How to correctly write the type definition for this interface attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> type of string or a function callback in TypeScript?

Simple :

```
export interface IBaseFormConfig {
  hints?: string | { (arg: Map<string, any>): string };
}
```

## Docs

Its called a callable signature : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/content/docs/types/callable.html

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more on what that pair of curly brace for? Any reference in TS official site? Thanks

Comment: Hi @basarat, is there a reason you used `{ (arg: Map<string, any>): string }` as opposed to `(arg: Map<string, any>) => string` ?

Comment: @Paarth In this case they are same. There are some limitations around the arrow syntax as mentioned here https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/callable.html 